# Dynamic Route with react/axios, nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have this situation. I have on my database 8 tables that each one will be an end-point. Each table refers to store calls from different groups.
On my server-side node js/express and sequelize I have many routes to some jsons but I do not want to create 8 more routes to refers to each table.
And on my client-side, I am using react/Axios to consume my API in node js. I will show 8 tabs, each tab for each table.

I want to know if there is a way to use one route using Axios I think is a dynamic route to access my controller and get my data from different JSON per request.

Example:
My front-end:
localhost:3000/billing

```
tab 1 -> group 1 (table 1)
tab 2 -> group 2 (table 2)
tab 3 -> group 3 (table 3)
tab 4 -> group 4 (table 4)
tab 5 -> group 5 (table 5)
tab 6 -> group 6 (table 6)
tab 7 -> group 7 (table 7)
tab 8 -> group 8 (table 8)
```

My back-end:
Receiving a request with the name of the table and create a dynamic route to response with JSON

My code below
Server-side
Content.model.js

```
const sequelizePaginate = require('sequelize-paginate');
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
const group_1 = sequelize.define('group_1',{
      USER_ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      TIPO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      ORIGEM: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }, 
      DATA: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      HORA: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      DESTINO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      CIDADE_DESTINO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      DURACAO_REAL: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      CUSTO: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
        
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: false,
    });
    const group_2 = sequelize.define('group_2',{
      USER_ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      TIPO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      ORIGEM: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }, 
      DATA: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      HORA: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      DESTINO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      CIDADE_DESTINO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      DURACAO_REAL: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      CUSTO: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(13, 2)
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: false,
    })
    sequelizePaginate.paginate(group_1);
    sequelizePaginate.paginate(group_2);
    return {group_1, group_2};
  };


===============================================================================
  
Routes.js
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();


const ContentController = require('./controllers/ContentController2');

//Route

//reports
routes.get("/billing", ContentController.showBillingGroup);
routes.get("/billing/:name", ContentController.showBillingGroupParam);

module.exports = routes;

================================================================================


Controller2.js
const db = require('../models/Content_sequelize');
const Content = db.content;
module.exports = {
   async showBillingGroup(req, res){
        const { page = 1 } = req.query;
        const BillingDetailed = await Content.group_1.paginate({order:[
                                                                    ['ORIGEM', 'ASC'],
                                                                    ['DATA', 'ASC'],
                                                                    ['HORA', 'ASC']] ,page, paginate:10});
        // console.log(BillingDetailed)
        return res.json(BillingDetailed);
    },


    async showBillingGroupParam(req, res) {
        const { page = 1 } = req.query;
        var data = req.params.name;
        console.log("Param: ", data, "Res" );

        if (data === 'group_1' ){
            console.log('group_2', data);
            const BillingDetailed = await Content.group_2.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);    
        }
        if (data === 'group_2'){
            console.log('group_2', data);
            const BillingDetailed = await Content.group_2.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        }      
        
    },

    async showBillingGroupParam(req, res) {
        const { page = 1 } = req.query;
        const BillingDetailed = await Content.group_2.paginate({page, paginate:1});
        
        return res.json(BillingDetailed);
    },

}
====================================================================================================
```

On Client-Side

detail.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tabs from '../../../../tabs/tabs';
import Table from '../../table/table2';
import Data from '../../../../services/api';
// import { JsonToTable } from "react-json-to-table";
import './styles.css';

const heads = ["TIPO",
            "ORIGEM", 
            "DATA" ,
            "HORA",
            "DESTINO",
            "CIDADE DESTINO", 
            "DURAÇÃO",  
            "CUSTO ( R$ )"
        ]

export default class Detailed extends Component {
    state = {
            content: [],
            contentInfo: {},
            page: 1
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadContent();
    }

    loadContent = async (page = 1) => {
        try {
            const response = await Data.get(`/billing?page=${page}`);
            const post = await Data.post(`/billing/${name}`);
            const { docs, ...contentInfo } = response.data;
            this.setState({ content: docs, contentInfo, page});
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    };


    render() {
        const { content, page, contentInfo } = this.state;
        // console.log("Console: ", contentInfo.pages);
        return (
            <div>
                <Tabs className="tb">
                    <div name="group_1" label="group_1">
                        <div>
                            <Table Header={heads} data={content} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div name="group_2" label="group_2">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Test group_2</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div name="group_3" label="group_3">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Test group_3</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div name="group_4" label="group_4">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Test group_4</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div name="group_5" label="group_5">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Test group_5</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div name="group_6" label="group_6">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Test group_6</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div name="group_7" label="group_7">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Test group_7</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div name="group_8" label="group_8">
                        <div>
                            <h1>Test group_8</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

===========================================================================================
I use this only to show the calls in a table.
table2.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { TableSimple } from 'react-pagination-table';


const Table = ({Header ,data}) =>(
    <div>
        <TableSimple
            headers={Header}
            //{["TIPO","ORIGEM","DATA","HORA","DESTINO","CIDADE_DESTINO","DURACAO_REAL","CUSTO"]}
            data={data}
            columns="TIPO.ORIGEM.DATA.HORA.DESTINO.CIDADE_DESTINO.DURACAO_REAL.CUSTO"
            arrayOptions={["CUSTO",'all',"R$ "]}/>
    </div>
    
)

export default Table;
```

============================================================================================

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Banner from './components/banner';
import Billing from './components/pages/reports/billing/summarized/index';

const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Banner/>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/billing" component={Billing}/>
            <Route exact path="/billing/:id" component={Billing}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

===============================================================================================

Axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001/api'
});

export default api;
```

Comment: Did you solve the dynamic api endpoint and just the react side is incomplete ?

Comment: I got it. I think it is not a beautiful way but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my mind and I have redo somethings.
First of all, I changed the inner tabs and used another component. One that I could get the index when the user clicks it.

```
<Tabs className="tabs" onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <Tab className={this.state.setValue === 0 ? "activated" : "tab"} label="group 1"/>
    <Tab className={this.state.setValue === 1 ? "activated" : "tab"} label="group 2"/>
    <Tab className={this.state.setValue === 2 ? "activated" : "tab"} label="group 3"/>
    <Tab className={this.state.setValue === 3 ? "activated" : "tab"} label="group 4"/>
    <Tab className={this.state.setValue === 4 ? "activated" : "tab"} label="group 5"/>
    <Tab className={this.state.setValue === 5 ? "activated" : "tab"} label="group 6"/>
    <Tab className={this.state.setValue === 6 ? "activated" : "tab"} label="group 7"/>
    <Tab className={this.state.setValue === 7 ? "activated" : "tab"} label="group 8"/>
</Tabs>
<div className="table">
    <Table Header={heads} data={content}/>
</div>
```

After that, I have created the function handleChange.

```
handleChange = async (event, newValue) => {
    try {
        const page = 1;
        const value = newValue;
        const post = await Data.post(`/billing/${value}?page=${page}`);
        const { docs, ...contentInfo } = post.data
        this.setState({setValue:value, content: docs, contentInfo, page});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

And I updated the loadContent function to this

```
loadContent = async (page = 1) => {
    try {
        const route = this.state.setValue === null ? null : this.state.setValue;
        const post = await Data.post(`/billing/${route}?page=${page}`);
        const { docs, ...contentInfo } = post.data
        // console.log("Docs", response.data);
        // const { docs, ...contentInfo } = response.data;
        this.setState({ content: docs, contentInfo, page, route});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

So I will send the tab index as a route to my back-end and in my back-end, I did this.

Controller2.js

```
async showBillingGroupParam(req, res) {
    const { page = 1 } = req.query;
    const data = req.params.id;
    let BillingDetailed = '0';
    switch(data){
        case '0':
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_1.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        case '1':
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_2.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        case '2':
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_3.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        case '3':
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_4.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        case '4':
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_5.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        case '5':
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_6.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        case '6':
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_7.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        case '7':
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_8.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
        default:
            BillingDetailed = await Content.group_1.paginate({page, paginate:10});
            return res.json(BillingDetailed);
    }
```

Content.model.js
In this file, I do not have another idea so I have coded the 8 models referring my 8 tables.

```
const group_1 = sequelize.define('group_1',{
      USER_ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      TIPO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      ORIGEM: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }, 
      DATA: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      HORA: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      DESTINO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      CIDADE_DESTINO: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      DURACAO_REAL: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      CUSTO: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
        
      }
    }
```

with all these changes I got I wanted